# How do I study the varition of the function $f(x) =\sqrt{-|x|}$ in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I want to know how can I study the variation of the function $f(x) =\sqrt{-|x|}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and how I can  draw  it's graph?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: For drawing the graph, I suppose you can just put a dot at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you for your edition

Answer (score 5):

The function is defined only for $x = 0$, and its value is $f(0) = 0$. The graph of the function is **only** the point $(0,0) \in \Bbb R^2$. Like this:

[image]

This is because: $${\rm gr}(f) = \{  (x,f(x)) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid x \in {\rm dom}(f) \} = \{ (0,0) \},$$ since ${\rm dom}(f) = \{0\}$.

<strike>Honestly, there is nothing to analyze in this function.</strike>

We have that $f$ is an odd function. It is also an even function at the same time.

Since $0$ is an isolated point of ${\rm dom}(f)$, $f$ is continuous. Hence, $f$ is Riemann-integrable and Lebesgue-integrable, and we have: $$\int_{{\rm dom}(f)}f(x)\,{\rm d}x = \int_{{\rm dom}(f)}f(x)\,{\rm d}{\frak m}(x) = f(0)\,{\frak m}(\{0\})=0,$$where $\frak m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R$. Also, $f$ is of bounded variation, $f$ is a closed map and a homeomorphism onto its image.

Moreover, $f$ is a linear map, since for all $x,y \in {\rm dom}(f)$ and $\lambda \in \Bbb R$ we have: $$f(x+\lambda y) = f(x)+\lambda f(y).$$

<sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>huehuehue [BR](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>

Comment: there is what you can analysis :The continuity at x=0!!!

Comment: Well, $0$ is an isolated point of ${\rm dom}(f)$, so $f$ is continuous at $0$...

Comment: Hence $f$ is integrable!

Comment: so you can edit your answer .

Comment: Sure thing, boss. If I think of more things I'll add there.

Comment: as they would say in the interwebs: "dat analysis! Kreygasm"

Comment: it's seems a simple function but it's very wide for using many area of math

Comment: @zeraouliarafik if this has answered your question please accept the answer.

Comment: I think that you forget to show that is :even function

Comment: I love how overkill this answer was.